# PCM1804 Output distorted

Tags: adc, output

I am using an TI PCM1804 to convert my audio signal.

The PCM1804 is configured as follows:
Master Mode, with 12.288MHz input clock
Sample rate: 48kHz

The testsignal is a 440Hz sine with an amplitude of 4.5V_pp. In order to get a balanced signal from the signal generator, I use a circuit which is identical to the one in the PCM1804 evaluation kit:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sleu015/sleu015.pdf

The circuit looks as follows:
[image: Circuit]

After analyzing the ouput, unfortunately there is no 440 Hz sine but a distorted signal. I can post a picture of it in the next post.

Can anybody help with this issue? I have no idea where this comes from.
Thanks in advance!
audio_horrible

Output picture:
[image]

Comment: Screenshot of the output can be found here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/us1iy.png

Comment: Reduce a lower input voltage and what do you get? Also what audio analyzer are you using?

Comment: Analyzer is Saleae Logic 8, Audio analyzation via Matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ADC is returning the data as signed (two's complement).  But you're treating it as if it was unsigned.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Here's a table (taken directly from Wikipedia) that explains what happens:

```
Bits   Signed    Unsigned

011    3         3
010    2         2
001    1         1
000    0         0
111    -1        7
110    -2        6
101    -3        5
100    -4        4
```

The "distortion" you see is caused by that transformation.

There should be some option in the software you use where you can select if the data is signed or unsigned.  Anyone who knows more about that is free to edit my answer.